# How can I extract time from Mon Oct 01 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Defining State values

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment(),
      startTime: moment(),
      endDate: moment(),
      endTime: moment(),
     }
   }
```

These are my date and time selection components

```
<FormGroup row>
   <Col md="3"><span>Start Date</span><Datetime dateFormat={true} timeFormat={false} onChange={this.handleStartDate.bind(this)}/></Col>
   <Col md="3"><span>Start Time</span><Datetime dateFormat={false} timeFormat={true} onChange={this.handleStartTime.bind(this)}/></Col>
   <Col md="3"><span>End Date</span><Datetime dateFormat={true} timeFormat={false} onChange={this.handleEndDate.bind(this)}/></Col>
   <Col md="3"><span>End Time</span><Datetime dateFormat={false} timeFormat={true} onChange={this.handleEndTime.bind(this)}/></Col>
</FormGroup>
```

And the onChange functions are

```
// start date 
  handleStartDate(date) {
    this.setState({startDate: date});
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
// start time 
  handleStartTime(time) {
    this.setState({ startTime: time });
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
// end date 
  handleEndDate(date) {
    this.setState({ endDate: date });
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
// end time 
  handleEndTime(time) {
    this.setState({ endTime: time });
    this.forceUpdate()
  }
```

On the final submit button I want to get the time only when selecting the time option, When I'm trying to console the time the returning value is

```
  submitClick(){
  console.log(this.state.endTime)//returns the value like Mon Oct 01 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
}
```

Please help me to extract time only from Mon Oct 01 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your as using the moment library, you can use the [format function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) to suit to your needs.

For example:

```
console.log(moment(this.state.endTime).format("HH:mm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment(this.state.endTime).format("h:mm:ss a")`

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow. If you can it would be useful to improve your answer with some context to how the moment api works, and why this provides an answer to the question.